# Trouble with arrays and formatting in java

Tags: java, arrays

I really could use a little bit of help if anyone could lend me a hand here, I've been working on an assignment for my introductory computer science class, but I've missed several classes and haven't had any time to study recently due to an unexpected family tragedy and quite frankly I have no idea what I'm doing and not much time to catch up right now. I've missed pretty much everything on arrays and don't have access to any of the in class materials covering the subject.

This is is the code I have right now

```
 * WeatherMonth.java 
 */

public class WeatherMonth
{

    private int [] maxTemperature;
    private String monthName;
    private int daysInMonth;


    public WeatherMonth()
    {
        monthName = "January";
        daysInMonth = 31;
        int [] maxTamperature = new int [daysInMonth];
        maxTemperature[0] = -999;
    }

    public WeatherMonth(String monthName, int daysInMonth)
    {
        this.monthName = monthName;
        this.daysInMonth = daysInMonth; 
        int days = maxTemperature.length;
        int [] maxTemperature = new int [days];
        maxTemperature[0] = -999;
        //int [] maxTemperature = [-999]
        //int [] maxTemperature.fill(daysInMonth, -999);
    }

    public int [] getMaxTemperature()
    {
        return maxTemperature;
    }

    public String getMonthName()
    {
        return monthName;
    }

    public int getDaysInMonth()
    {
        return daysInMonth;
    }

    public void setDayMaxTemp(int dayOfMonth, int temperature)
    {

    }

    public void setMaxTemperature(int [] maxTemperature)
    {
        this.maxTemperature = maxTemperature;
    }

    public void setMonthName(String monthName)
    {
        this.monthName = monthName;
    }

    public void setDaysInMonth(int daysInMonth)
    {
        this.daysInMonth = daysInMonth;
    }

    public void displayWeatherMonth()
    {

    }

    public void readMaxTempFile(String filename)
    {

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "";
    }

}
```

The following is the only thing close to a hint I've gotten on what to do to get this to work, as of now my constructors, setDayMaxTemp, and displayWeather methods aren't working for me.

check constructors

symptom: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
at WeatherMonth.(WeatherMonth.java:30)

check set day max temp

symptom: java.lang.NullPointerException

Fail in TestPrelabB. Method displayWeatherMonth is incorrect. Your output is not formatted exaclty as specified. Name of month is June and number of days is 2. This is the expected output: June Day Max 1 -999 2 -999 This is your output: Make sure you printed the month name first. Make sure you printed the header line. Make sure each line has a number and a temperature. Make sure tabs separate data items in each row including the header row.

This is the code for the tests I have to pass

```
 * TestPrelabB.java
 */
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class TestPrelabB
{
    /**
     * Check mutators to make sure 
     * properly.
     */
    @Test
    public void checkAccessorsMutators001()
    {
        checkStringAMMonthName("June");
        checkStringAMMonthName("July");
        checkIntAMDaysInMonth(5);
        checkIntAMDaysInMonth(7);
        checkIntArrayAMMaxTemperature(new int[]{1, 2});
        checkIntArrayAMMaxTemperature(new int[]{3, 4, 5});
    }      

    /**
     * Check constructors.
     */
    @Test
    public void checkConstructors002()
    {
        checkNoArgConstructor();
        check2ArgConstructor("June", 2);
        check2ArgConstructor("July", 3);
    }    

    /**
     * Make sure setDayMaxTemp functions properly with
     * in range data.
     */
    @Test
    public void checkSetDayMaxTemp003()
    {
        checkSetDayMaxTemp(2, 85);
        checkSetDayMaxTemp(5, 37);
        checkSetDayMaxTempMinMax();
        checkSetDayMaxTempOOB();
    }    

    /**
     * Make sure displayWeatherData prints properly.
     */
    @Test
    public void checkDisplayWeatherMonth004()
    {

        String answer1 = "";
        answer1 += "June\n";
        answer1 += "Day\tMax\n";
        answer1 += "1\t-999\n";
        answer1 += "2\t-999\n";

        String answer2 = "";
        answer2 += "June\n";
        answer2 += "Day\tMax\tMin\n";
        answer2 += "1\t-999\t-999\n";
        answer2 += "2\t-999\t-999\n";

        checkDisplayWeatherMonth("June", 2, answer1, answer2);

        answer1  = "August\n";
        answer1 += "Day\tMax\n";
        answer1 += "1\t-999\n";
        answer1 += "2\t-999\n";
        answer1 += "3\t-999\n";

        answer2  = "August\n";
        answer2 += "Day\tMax\tMin\n";
        answer2 += "1\t-999\t-999\n";
        answer2 += "2\t-999\t-999\n";
        answer2 += "3\t-999\t-999\n";

        checkDisplayWeatherMonth("August", 3, answer1, answer2);
    }

    /**
     * Check 2-arg constructor.
     * @param monthName The initial name of this WeatherMonth.
     * @param daysInMonth The initial number of days in this WeatherMonth.
     */
    public void check2ArgConstructor(String monthName,
        int daysInMonth)
    {
        String fb = "";
        fb += "Fail in TestPrelabB.\n";
        fb += "2-arg constructor is incorrect.\n";        
        WeatherMonth weatherMonth = new WeatherMonth(monthName,
            daysInMonth);

        int[] temps = null;
        try
        {
            temps = weatherMonth.getMaxTemperature();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            temps = null;
        }

        if (!weatherMonth.getMonthName().equals(monthName))
        {
            fb += "Field monthName was not set correctly.";
            fail(fb);
        }
        else if (temps == null) 
        {
            fb += "Field maxTemperature was left null.";
            fail(fb);
        }
        else if (temps.length != daysInMonth)
        {
            fb += "Field maxTemperature does not have the ";
            fb += "correct length.";
            fail(fb);
        }
        else 
        {
            boolean fail = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++)
            {
                if (temps[i] != -999)
                {
                    fail = true;
                }
            }
            if (fail)
            {
                fb += "Not All values in maxTemperature were "; 
                fb += "initialized to -999.";
                fail(fb);                
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check 2-arg constructor.
     */
    public void checkNoArgConstructor()
    {
        String fb = "";
        fb += "Fail in TestPrelabB.\n";
        fb += "No-arg constructor is incorrect.\n";        

        WeatherMonth weatherMonth = new WeatherMonth();

        int[] temps = null;
        try
        {
            temps = weatherMonth.getMaxTemperature();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            temps = null;
        }

        if (!weatherMonth.getMonthName().equals("January"))
        {
            fb += "Field monthName was not set correctly.";
            fail(fb);
        }
        else if (temps == null) 
        {
            fb += "Field maxTemperature was left null.";
            fail(fb);
        }
        else if (temps.length != 31)
        {
            fb += "Field maxTemperature does not have the ";
            fb += "correct length.";
            fail(fb);
        }
        else 
        {
            boolean fail = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++)
            {
                if (temps[i] != -999)
                {
                    fail = true;
                }
            }
            if (fail)
            {
                fb += "Not All values in maxTemperature were "; 
                fb += "initialized to -999.";
                fail(fb);                
            }
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Check display weather data with data.
     * 
     * Activity 3 requires modification of this method.  both answers
     * must be allowed here to keep the modifications in activity 3 
     * from causing a failure here.  As long as the answer matches one
     * of the two posibilities it is given a pass here.
     * 
     * @param name The name of this WeatherMonth for testing.
     * @param days The number of days in this month for testing.
     * @param answer1 The correct, expected result of the students output
     * after completing the prelab.
     * @param answer2 The correct, expected result of the students output
     * after the student has completed activity 3.  
     */
    public void checkDisplayWeatherMonth(String name, int days,
        String answer1, String answer2)
    {
        String fb = "";
        fb += "Fail in TestPrelabB.\n";
        fb += "Method displayWeatherMonth is incorrect.\n";         
        String output = captureDisplayWeatherData(name, days);

        if (!output.equals(answer1) && !output.equals(answer2))
        {
            fb += "Your output is not formatted exactly as specified.\n";
            fb += "Name of month is " + name + " and number of days\n";
            fb += "is " + days + ".\n";
            fb += "This is the expected output:\n";
            fb += answer1;
            fb += "\nThis is your output:\n";
            fb += output;
            fb += "\nMake sure you printed the month name first.\n";
            fb += "Make sure you printed the header line.\n";
            fb += "Make sure each line has a number and a temperature.\n";
            fb += "Make sure tabs separate data items in each row\n";
            fb += "including the header row.\n";
            fail(fb);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the setDayMaxTemp method with data.
     * @param day The day to set the given temperature.
     * @param temp The temperature to set.
     */
    public void checkSetDayMaxTemp(int day, int temp)
    {
        String fb = "";
        fb += "Fail in TestPrelabB.\n";
        fb += "Method setDayMaxTemp is incorrect.\n";           

        WeatherMonth weatherMonth = new WeatherMonth("June",
            day + 2);
        weatherMonth.setDayMaxTemp(day, temp);

        int[] temps = weatherMonth.getMaxTemperature();

        //Check all locations EXCEPT for the correct one.
        for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++)
        {
            if (i != day - 1)
            {
                if (temps[i] == temp)
                {
                    fb += "Temperature is stored in the wrong position.\n";
                    fb += "Ran setDayMaxTemp(" + day + "," + temp + ");\n";
                    fb += temp + " should have been stored at location ";
                    fb += (day - 1) + "\n";
                    fb += temp + " was found at location " + i + ".\n";
                    fail(fb);
                }
            }
        }

        //Check to see if the correct temp is stored at the correct
        //location.
        if (temps[day - 1] != temp)
        {
            fb += "Temperature is not stored in the array.\n";
            fb += "Ran setDayMaxTemp(" + day + "," + temp + ");\n";
            fb += temp + " should have been stored at location ";
            fb += (day - 1) + "\n";
            fail(fb);            
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the setDayMaxTempMinMax method with data.
     * This method is here simply because the boundaries were not
     * being tested in the prelab test, where it should have been.
     * 
     */
    public void checkSetDayMaxTempMinMax()
    {
        String fb = "";
        fb += "Fail in TestPrelabB.\n";
        fb += "Method setDayMaxTemp is incorrect.\n";           

        WeatherMonth weatherMonth = new WeatherMonth("Test", 31);
        weatherMonth.setDayMaxTemp(1, 85);
        weatherMonth.setDayMaxTemp(31, 95);

        int[] temps = weatherMonth.getMaxTemperature();

        //Check to see if the correct temp is stored at the correct
        //location.
        if (temps[0] != 85)
        {
            fb += "You did not allow temperature setting on day 1.\n";
            fb += "Ran setDayMaxTemp(1, 85);\n";
            fb += "85 should have been stored at location 0.\n";
            fb += "You had " + temps[0] + " at location 0.\n";
            fail(fb);            
        }

        if (temps[30] != 95)
        {
            fb += "You did not allow temperature setting on last day of month.\n";
            fb += "Ran setDayMaxTemp(31, 95); on a month with 31 days.\n";
            fb += "95 should have been stored at location 30.\n";
            fb += "You had " + temps[30] + " at location 30.\n";
            fail(fb);            
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the setDayMaxTemp method with out of bounds data.
     */
    public void checkSetDayMaxTempOOB()
    {
        String fb = "";
        fb += "Fail in TestPrelabB.\n";
        fb += "Method setDayMaxTemp is incorrect.\n";           

        WeatherMonth weatherMonth = new WeatherMonth("June", 2);
        try 
        {
            weatherMonth.setDayMaxTemp(0, 95);
            weatherMonth.setDayMaxTemp(3, 95);
            weatherMonth.setDayMaxTemp(10, 95);

            int[] temps = weatherMonth.getMaxTemperature();

            //Check all locations to make sure none changed.
            for (int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++)
            {
                if (temps[i] != -999)
                {
                    fb += "This method should not allow setting of data\n";
                    fb += "for days less than 1 or days greater than the\n";
                    fb += "number of days in the month.\n";
                    fb += "Your method incorrectly changed the temperature\n";
                    fb += "in the maxTemperature array when given a day\n";
                    fb += "outside of the allowed range.\n";
                    fb += "You should ignore out of bounds days.\n";
                    fail(fb);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            fb += "This method should not allow setting of data\n";
            fb += "for days less than 1 or days greater than the\n";
            fb += "number of days in the month.\n";
            fb += "Your method attempted to change the temperature\n";
            fb += "in the maxTemperature array when given a day\n";
            fb += "outside of the allowed range.\n";
            fb += "You should ignore out of bounds days.\n";
            fail(fb);           
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the monthName accessor and mutator with normal valid data.
     * @param testData The monthName to set for testing.
     */
    public void checkStringAMMonthName(String testData)
    {
        String fb = "";
        fb += "Fail in TestPrelabB.\n";
        fb += "Accessor or mutator for monthName field is incorrect.\n";

        WeatherMonth weatherMonth = new WeatherMonth("", 1);
        weatherMonth.setMonthName(testData + "X");                       
        String setData = weatherMonth.getMonthName();

        if (setData == null)
        {
            fb += "Field is null after setting valid data.";
            fail(fb);                
        }            
        else if (!setData.equals(testData + "X"))
        {
            fb += "Field value is incorrect after setting valid data.";
            fail(fb);                
        }       
    } 

    /**
     * Determine if two int arrays are equal in size
     * and each element matches.
     * @param a The first array for equality checking.
     * @param b The second array for equality checking.
     * @return Returns true if a and b are both the same
     * length and each element matches.
     */
    private boolean intArrayEquals(int[] a, int[] b)
    {        
        if (a == b)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (a.length != b.length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            //Check each element.  Arrays are unequal if even one
            //is different.
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] != b[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        //Same length and all elements are the same.
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check the monthName accessor and mutator with normal valid data.
     * @param testData The monthName to set for testing.
     */
    public void checkIntArrayAMMaxTemperature(int[] testData)
    {
        String fb = "";
        fb += "Fail in TestPrelabB.\n";
        fb += "Accessor or mutator for maxTemperature field is incorrect.\n";

        WeatherMonth weatherMonth = new WeatherMonth("", 1);
        weatherMonth.setMaxTemperature(testData);                       
        int[] setData = weatherMonth.getMaxTemperature();

        if (setData == null)
        {
            fb += "Field is null after setting valid data.";
            fail(fb);                
        }            
        else if (!intArrayEquals(testData, setData))
        {
            fb += "Field value is incorrect after setting valid data.\n";
            fb += "Set array and get array differ in size or\n";
            fb += "one or more elements are different.\n";
            fail(fb);                
        }       
    } 

    /**
     * Check the daysInMonth accessor and mutator with normal valid data.
     * @param testData The monthName to set for testing.
     */
    public void checkIntAMDaysInMonth(int testData)
    {
        String fb = "";
        fb += "Fail in TestPrelabB.\n";
        fb += "Accessor or mutator for daysInMonth field is incorrect.";

        int initData = 1;
        if (testData == 1)
        {
            initData = 2;
        }

        WeatherMonth weatherMonth = new WeatherMonth("", initData);
        weatherMonth.setDaysInMonth(testData);                       
        int setData = weatherMonth.getDaysInMonth();

        if (setData != testData)
        {
            fail(fb);
        }       
    }     

    /**
     * Capture student output.
     * @param name The name of this WeatherMonth for testing.
     * @param days The number of days in this WeatherMonth.
     * @return Returns the output of the student output data as an
     * array of strings.
     */
    public String captureDisplayWeatherData(String name, int days)
    {
        String fb = "";
        //Scanner testInput = new Scanner(testData);

        //terminal now prints to the Terminal Window like this
        //      terminal.println("Hello");
        PrintStream terminal = System.out;

        //Set up System to print to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(output));

        //Run the students method and capture the results.

        WeatherMonth weatherMonth = new WeatherMonth(name, days);
        weatherMonth.displayWeatherMonth();
        System.out.flush();

        //Print user output to terminal
        //terminal.println(output);

        //Restore printing
        System.setOut(terminal);

        //Replace all crnl with nl
        //Replace all cr with nl
        //Only nl should remain
        String studentData = output.toString();
        studentData = studentData.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n");
        studentData = studentData.replaceAll("\r", "\n");

        //Split the lines into an array of strings
        //return studentData.split("\n");          
        return studentData;

    }

}
```

I really want to apologize for asking for help like this, I'm just at a loss right now and not even really sure where to start with this. I'm sorry if this isn't very clear or if I'm asking for far too much here. I welcome anything that might help me.

Comment: Please include a _minimal_ example.

Comment: First, I am sorry for your personal circumstances, but this information is completely irrelevant in SO. Second, nobody is going to debug your code. Please, try to create a snippet with the minimum amount of code that will fail. Then, if you don't happen to find the problem by yourself, post it and maybe someone will be able to help you. But nobody is going to finish your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that there are many bugs with this code, but firstly compare your constructors (comments added)

```
public WeatherMonth()
{
    monthName = "January";
    daysInMonth = 31;
    // this array is being initialized OK, but it is shadowing the field of the same name, 
    // so comment it out and replace with maxTamperature = new int [daysInMonth]; 
    int [] maxTamperature = new int [daysInMonth];  
    maxTemperature[0] = -999;
}

public WeatherMonth(String monthName, int daysInMonth)
{
    this.monthName = monthName;
    this.daysInMonth = daysInMonth; 
    int days = maxTemperature.length;      
    // maxTemperature has not been initialized yet, this is meaningless, use the same logic as your other constructor above
    int [] maxTemperature = new int [days];
    maxTemperature[0] = -999;
    //int [] maxTemperature = [-999]
    //int [] maxTemperature.fill(daysInMonth, -999);
}
```